# Potentially overthinking transformations of functions... need confirmation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So this may be really simple. The question is

> Write the equation of the transformed function $y=x^2$ after the following transformation in the order given.
>
> - a vertical compression by a factor of $\frac13$ followed by a transformation of $3$ units right.

Isn't this just $y=3\left((x-3)^2\right)$?

I feel as though I'm overthinking it.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

For any function $y=f(x)$, transformations can be described by the equation
$$y=af[k(x-c)]+d$$
where $|a|$ is the vertical dilation, $|k|$ is the horizontal dilation, $c$ is the horizontal translation, and $d$ is the vertical translation.  If $a<0$, there is a vertical reflection, and if $k<0$, there is a horizontal reflection.

Thus, a vertical compression by a factor of $3$ would mean $a=\frac13$, and a horizontal translation $3$ units right would mean $c=3$.  Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x^2\\
y=\frac13f(x-3)&=\frac13(x-3)^2
\end{align}

You've got the right answer!

Comment: A quick note:  "compression by a factor of $\frac13$" makes little sense (to me, and to many texts, and is why I chose to word my solution alternatively).  The words "expansion" and "compression" already determine the direction of dilation, and so we can always consider that "expand" means to multiply by the factor and "compress" means to divide by the factor.

Comment: Thank you! That answers my question.